# Iterating over every multisite / theme and list the pages

Tags: multisite, themes, pages

is there a way to iterate over every multisite page and list their sub pages? In my case every multisite has it's own theme so iterating over every theme would be a possibility.

My Code so far:

```
$get_guid = [];
$theme = wp_get_theme();
$temp = $theme-> template;
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/";

function list_pages(){
global $path;
global $get_guid;
global $temp;

$filename = $path . $temp . "_list.json";
$getPages = get_pages();

foreach ($getPages as $pages){
    array_push($get_guid, $pages->guid);
}

$file_list = fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($file_list, json_encode($get_guid, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR, 512 ));
fclose($file_list);

}

register_activation_hook(
__FILE__,
'list_pages'
);
```

Comment: I wrote a plugin that does this "CellarWeb Multisite Post Reader". Uses a shortcode with optional parameters to filter the posts that are displayed. Since it is open-source, you can use it or look at the code and roll your own.

Comment: thanks, actually a comment in your code helped me a lot:
https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/how-to-list-posts-from-all-blogs-on-wordpress-multisite/

Answer (score 0):

due to Rick Hellewells comment I could write a code, which iterates over every blog (as a blog is a new mulitiste site) and outputs it's site on plugin activation.

See this link: https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/how-to-list-posts-from-all-blogs-on-wordpress-multisite/

As every site has it's own theme, the $temp variable can hold the wp_get_theme command (you could also extract the site's name with it's path and the explode() command), also note, that I would recommend to put the restore_current_blog() command outside of the foreach loop, so it won't execute this command on every iteration as mentioned in the link above:

```
function pages_of_multisite_on_activation() {
global $path;

// loop through all blogs
$blog_ids = get_sites();

foreach ($blog_ids as $current_blog) {
    // switch to each blog to get the posts
    $blog_id = $current_blog->blog_id;

    switch_to_blog($blog_id);

    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    $temp = $theme-> template;

    // fetch all the posts
    $getPages = get_pages();

    $filename = $path . $temp . "ending.json";

    write_page_ids($getPages, $filename);

}

restore_current_blog();

}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'pages_of_multisite_on_activation' );
```

Comment: Note that, by default, [`get_sites()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/) only gets up to 100 sites. If you've got a larger Multisite network, you'll need to use the `number` argument: `$blog_ids = get_sites( array( 'number' => 1000 ) );`